# Append string in Pandas DataFrame with cumulative count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pd.DataFrame` full of picture names. Often, the image names are repeated. **But**, they are always next to each other. This is what it looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(['image_{}'.format(randint(4)) for i in range(10)]),
     columns=['Image Name'])

print(df)
```

```
Out[6]: 
  Image Name
0    image_0
1    image_0
2    image_0
3    image_1
4    image_1
5    image_2
6    image_2
7    image_2
8    image_3
9    image_3
```

Because I will save the images based on this name, I want to append these strings with the cumulative count, as such:

```
Out[7]: 
  Image Name
0    image_0_1
1    image_0_2
2    image_0_3
3    image_1_1
4    image_1_2
5    image_2_1
6    image_2_2
7    image_2_3
8    image_3_1
9    image_3_1
```

How can I proceed? I'm guessing some combination of `groupby` and `cumcount`?

Comment: Same as above: `df['Image Name'].str.cat(df.groupby('Image Name').cumcount().add(1).astype(str), sep='_')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider [`groupby().cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and concatenate to original string and order does not matter:

```
df['Image Name'] = (df['Image Name'] + '_' + 
                      (df.groupby('Image Name').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
                   )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df['new_name'] = (
    df
    .groupby('Image Name')['Image Name']
    .transform(lambda images: [image + f'_{n + 1}' for n, image in enumerate(images)])
)
>>> df
  Image Name   new_name
0    image_0  image_0_1
1    image_0  image_0_2
2    image_0  image_0_3
3    image_1  image_1_1
4    image_1  image_1_2
5    image_2  image_2_1
6    image_2  image_2_2
7    image_2  image_2_3
8    image_3  image_3_1
9    image_3  image_3_2
```